# Parsely javascript form validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to validate my bootstrap form with `Parsely` javascript validator. 
Below is the link -http://parsleyjs.org/

However there is a problem. I noticed that the validations do not work until I put `data-parsley-validate` into the `<form>` attribute. However in their tutorial, they have clearly mentioned not to use `data-parsley-validate`. Below is the link - http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-installation-javascript

My question is, how can I validate properly without using the `data-parsley-validate` attribute?

Comment: The tutorial states that you either add the `data-parsely-validate` attribute to the form, *or* you manually install it with your own JavaScript.

Comment: @Blender: Which means, I don't have to use `$('#form').parsley();` if I use the `data-parsely-validate` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what the docs say.

Answer (score 1):

`data-parsley-validate` by documentation,

> Auto bind your form with Parsley validation on document load.

If you want to avoid that (auto binding your form to parsley), you manually bind your `form` to parsley on document load like,

```
$('#form').parsley();
```

With respect to them mentioning not to use `data-parsley-validate`, they're just asking you to be ***cautious*** about repeating instantiations, meaning,

if you add a `data-parsley-validate` to your form with id `#myForm`, and then you instantiate `parsley` manually (again) on this form using,

```
$("#myForm").parsley(option); //options are your custom options
```

it will return the automatically bound instance, and not the manually bound instance. You may use *either* of the methods to instantiate `parsley` on your form, but **NOT** both.

Comment: I want to know why they mentioned not to use `data-parsley-validate` ? It is easy to use it, but they said not to, eventhough all of their examples are full ofthem.